# How parse makeHttpRequest with friendly url?

Tags: android, json, url

I have a web service that return a json data
my url is :

http://myurl/1/40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef/ali/rezaie/1358-01-21/a@a.com/896523147/0912666666/02

http://myurl/param1/param2/param3/....

my parameters separated with / and no use ?

How can I send parameter to this url in android

I cant use parameter.add because I haven't key , my data is Tandem and without key like  this

```
parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[0]));
```

Comment: If you just need to add the correct params into the URL, use a StringBuilder in order to pen the URL :

Comment: my url is http://myurl/param1/param2/param3/....